# What am I doing wrong with this Firebase snippet I found multiple times around the web?

Tags: typescript, firebase, firebase-authentication

Consider:

[image]

`Property 'auth' does not exist on type 'typeof import("/home/nuhutuh25/Desktop/ignition/registry/node_modules/firebase/app/dist/app/index")'.ts(2339)`

I did install Firebase as a dependency and also saw someone successfully writing `const auth=app.auth()`, but that does not work either, because type FirebaseApp doesn't have any attribute *auth*.

I am using TypeScript.

Comment: Install firebase locally? What? Does that project has the firebase libraries included? Did you add the dependencies in the package.json?

Comment: Oh sorry I meant I ran yarn add firebase

Comment: Please review *[Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/)* (e.g., *"Images should only be used to illustrate problems that* ***can't be made clear in any other way***, *such as to provide screenshots of a user interface."*) and take the appropriate [action](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/69872942/edit) (it covers answers as well).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems you have the new Firebase Modular SDK installed (`V9.0.0+`) which has a new syntax unlike the older name-spaced one. If you want to keep using existing syntax you can switch to `compat` version:

```
import firebase from "firebase/compat/app"
import "firebase/compat/auth"
```

I would recommend [upgrading to Modular SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/modular-upgrade#get_the_version_9_sdk) because the compat libraries are a temporary solution that will be removed completely in a future major SDK version.

Try refactoring your code as shown below:

```
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
import { getAuth } from "firebase/auth";

const app = initializeApp({...firebaseConfig});

export const auth = getAuth(app);
```